# How can I deal with someone repeatedly pasting the same comment after it is removed

Tags: discussion

I recently added an answer to a question that is several years old, because the facts have changed and the existing answer (which is still good) is outdated.

Another user noticed this and downvoted my answer so that he could add his own answer just to promote his library. His answer lists things not to do and his library link (as opposed to answering what *to* do)

But now that user has been leaving a condescending comment on my answer over and over and over, despite the content of his comment being incorrect due to bad assumptions. SO just removes the comment and then I get an email that he has pasted it back again.

I raised a mod flag saying that he is doing it repeatedly, but the amount you can type is limited. I know there has been recent discussion on harassing behaviour - so **what else can I do besides keep flagging the comment?** At this point it is harassment and it is tiring. I am *assuming* he is hoping it will lead to me deleting my answer or others downvoting my answer so that his library gets attention, but I don't want to delete my answer, because it *is* useful, with an example and link which are missing in the existing answer.

I thought there would be an automatic script that detects identical comments being posted again and again, but nothing is stopping him.

Comment: Did you actually mod-flag? Try to shorten your description - it shouldn't be very long.

Comment: Yes and they marked it helpful, but a few mins later i received another comment notification. I don't want to have to harass the mods over and over. I wanted to type more to explain that I thought he was doing it because he wants to promote the library

Comment: To be clear it's not in different places. The guy isn't spamming all my answers. Its on the same post each time it gets removed. I don't think he is specifically trying to attack me, I feel like it's just because he want's his library answer to stand out

Comment: Looking at that situation, it would look to me like he's acting in good faith (whether technically correct or not) and just wants to have his opinion heard by pointing out a perceived flaw in your answer. Since he's repeatedly seeing his comment getting removed, he's simply reposting it. Maybe a bit too persistent, but that's really what comments are supposed to be for: pointing out issues with posts.

Comment: @deceze is there a better way for the commenter to proceed if they feel their comment is being deleted unfairly? (Assuming they know that's what's happening.) Repeatedly reposting it if they know it's been deleted by moderators doesn't seem like the best way to go about it even if they are acting in good faith as far as the original intent of the comment.

Comment: @Don't You could flag the post, asking a moderator to deal with what you perceive to be unfair deletion. But really, I'd hope at some point you'd just let it be instead of causing even more flags. Comments are and always were seen as ephemeral.

Comment: Is the commenter correct about the technical issue he's raising?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not that it's really the point of this question, but no, he's neither right about the content of the existing answer, nor about the ability to decide when to inject, nor about which parts of the code are relevant (nor about the points in his own answer). I have my answer used in a production extension (as the documentation I linked teaches).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197583/discussion-on-question-by-nick-cardoso-how-can-i-deal-with-someone-repeatedly-pa).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As George already pointed out a custom mod flag is the way to go here. Do notice that there is stricter limit on a custom comment flag then there is on a custom flag on a post (question or answer). **If you really can't do** with the amount of characters the custom flag on a comment provides **flag your own answer**. You will have around 300 extra characters to add to that flag description.

Answer (score 9):

I've been spending an inordinate amount of time on these posts, comments and flags. Indeed there was a flag about the comments being deleted. To which I replied:

> if your comment is deleted. stop reposting it. Clearly the comments are being flagged

Flag and move on. Flag as no longer needed, the comments were not rude, the person was offering a technical opinion.  ***If*** the person persists, raise a custom flag and allow the moderators to deal with it. There isn't an auto flag to tell moderators that the person is repeatedly posting the same comment, unless the comment is deleted as rude/unkind.

The best thing you can do is not get into a debate with someone who persists on commenting under your post when you don't want to engage. You've done the right thing by flagging, that way is the person persists to a point that is beyond unreasonable disciplinary action can be taken if needed. The problem lies when people (and it's understandable people do this) try to take matters into their own hands by replying. Conversations tend to deteriorate quickly in these types of circumstances and then that can involve two people being censured.

When two users regularly cross paths and the communication doesn't go well, I generally advise them to avoid interacting.

Comment: The guy commented on a question several years old only because i had, then proceeded to condescendingly state as fact easily debunkable things which are blatantly untrue about my answer. That absolutely fits my definition of rude, if not yours. But then he broke the rules/common decency by keep checking back and reposting the same thing, for the sake of conflict. Then he broke the rules again by duplicating his answer just because he received deserved downvotes on a factually incorrect ad for his library.

Comment: @NickCardoso and as I mentioned in my answer that person was dealt with. Did you see my declined flag reason? The comments were not outright rude, it was the persistence. So really what issues do you have? I've agreed with everything except that the comments themselves were rude - it was the repetition. I didn't decline your flag on the other post, I marked it helpful. I declined the other user's post flag

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with your actions or complaining how you dealt with me (of course until now I have no idea how/whether you deal with the other person). I'm just telling you I feel justified in flagging it as rude.

Comment: He's also added two more comments, just to persist. Again with false information (you can literally click the first link in my post and search activeTab to prove this, if it matters).

Absolutely not good faith.

Comment: @NickCardoso please ping me here if there is one more comment from this user or raise a flag with a link to this post.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is a custom mod flag that gives us a link to the post(s) where you've seen this link continually re-posted and flagged. We can see all of that, and will handle it based on that. Something like "This user keeps reposting this comment here (link) and here (link), and I keep flagging it. Letting you know in case further steps need to be taken."

There are stock comments that users use through their userscripts that can be annoying in large numbers but aren't individually problematic; and then there are the ones that are annoying and problematic. You won't be dinged for custom mod flagging us in good faith about either.